# Is this an overscan issue or how can I fix this?

Tags: pi-4, display

I have a Raspberry Pi 4 with Raspbian as operating system. This is connected to my TV via HDMI. Unfortunately, the display of the operating system on the TV is not perfect.

The display of the system is too deep in the corners on the left and right (see pictures).
[image]

I have also fiddled around in the config.txt file, but still the same problem. Here is the current content of the config.txt file (see attachment).

And this what the config.txt file contains:

```
GNU nano 7.2                                                                                                                                                                                                            
# For more options and information see
# http://rptl.io/configtxt
# Some settings may impact device functionality. See link above for details

# Uncomment some or all of these to enable the optional hardware interfaces
#dtparam=i2c_arm=on
#dtparam=i2s=on
#dtparam=spi=on

# Enable audio (loads snd_bcm2835)
dtparam=audio=on

# Additional overlays and parameters are documented
# /boot/firmware/overlays/README

# Automatically load overlays for detected cameras
camera_auto_detect=1

# Automatically load overlays for detected DSI displays
display_auto_detect=1

# Automatically load initramfs files, if found
auto_initramfs=1

# Enable DRM VC4 V3D driver
dtoverlay=vc4-kms-v3d
max_framebuffers=2

# Don't have the firmware create an initial video= setting in cmdline.txt.
# Use the kernel's default instead.
disable_fw_kms_setup=1

# Disable compensation for displays with overscan
disable_overscan=0

# uncomment the following to adjust overscan. Use positive numbers if console
# goes off screen, and negative if there is too much border
overscan_left=14
overscan_right=146
overscan_top=16
overscan_bottom=16

# Enable 1080p @60 Hz HDMI mode
hdmi_group=1
hdmi_mode=16

# Run as fast as firmware / board allows
arm_boost=1

[cm4]
# Enable host mode on the 2711 built-in XHCI USB controller.
# This line should be removed if the legacy DWC2 controller is required
# (e.g. for USB device mode) or if USB support is not required.
otg_mode=1

[all]
```

Comment: try  #dtoverlay=vc4-kms-v3d / disable_overscan=1 / are you sure you have correct hdmi group / hdmi mode?

Comment: try adjusting the monitor

Comment: I solved the issue. I had to adjust certain settings on my TV. Now its perfect!